# Git ignore all files in directory expect for specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitignore

My rails app uploads all users photos to a folder /uploads/photos/. I want to ignore everything in this folder in git except for one subfolder /uploads/photos/default/.

Is this possible using the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the prefix `!`

From the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> An optional prefix ! which negates the
>   pattern; any matching file excluded by
>   a previous pattern will become
>   included again. If a negated pattern
>   matches, this will override lower
>   precedence patterns sources.

```
# ignore generated html files,
*.html
# except foo.html which is maintained by hand
!foo.html
```

Although I wouldn't normally store user-generated content in the same hierarchy as my code base/repository.